# How to create Epic and Feature Documentation from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, documentation, document

I have multiple projects in Azure DevOps. In each of the projects Epics and Features will be assigned. I am looking for a way to document in narrative format these epics and features. This epic and feature document would be used to give to Marketing or other departments, that allows them to gain an understanding of the the products capabilities.

Is there any tool that can be used to create this kind of documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do most of our actual features and epics documentation in Office (Word, PowerPoint etc.) and store them in Microsoft SharePoint/Teams.

The features and epics in Azure DevOps are merely placeholders for our PBI's. Here we may put links to the "actual" documents. We don't have any "marketing" documents in DevOps. Even though most of the text areas are in "rich text" then it's not really editor friendly.

If you still would like to do it, then you could check out this extension from the Azure DevOps marketplace:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-enhanced-export

It allows you to export your features (and work items etc.) directly to Word, where you could "beautify" them further.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps does not have native reporting that outputs epic and feature information in easy to digest narrative documents. However, on a different note, third party tools like Azure Documenter integrated through custom scripts offer potential solutions to generate document for resources/applications deployed via Azure DevOps.

For example, if you want to generate a document on Azure DevOps pipeline, you can use Azure Documenter and PowerShell scripting which will allow you to automate document generation directly from your DevOps pipeline, ensuring that each deployment updates the documentation accordingly.

Maybe you can also check out this video for better understanding - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX02K4pZoFw